# Php dynamic subpage and nginx address rewriting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess, nginx

I created a website based on ajax tech. and now I want to achieve similar effects using php (nginx). The problem is I don't want to create (even dynamically) `.php` documents for every user or offer or anything. I have templates for every pages like `userTemplate.php` and it works fine with `$_GET` method, which fill it with proper data BUT the address is not acceptable, hoe can I convert that request`example.com/userTemplate.php?id=1` to `example.com/users/1.` I tried with rewriting it in config files, but then it redirects me to the path `/users/1` which is ofc wrong... Is it possible? Please I've already spent hours looking for any answer.

Comment: IMHO, it's way more likely that you'll get an answer, if you add your existing nginx config to your Question.

Comment: Ok, but now it's pure:
`code
 location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
         location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #       # With php5-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
`
What should be there to get it works?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location ~* /users/(\d+) {
    try_files $uri /userTemplate.php?id=$1;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    # With php5-cgi alone:
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #
    # With php5-fpm: 
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

If you want to go for an alternative approach, have a look at [Creating NGINX Rewrite Rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/). If you need different, more complicated regular expressions, perhaps start [here](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my problem and finally worked! I only had to add "$uri after try_files" :)

Comment: Right, added $uri